# "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property" using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate for the first time and am having trouble getting it to work with my schema.

I am getting "*org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Student.Faculty in Faculty.allStudents*".

Some students share a single mentor. I would think the student relation to faculty would be ManyToOne because of this, but I was told it is a OneToOne relation.

Student.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity  
@Table(name = "Student")  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="StudentID")
public class Student extends Person
{
    @Column(name = "Classification")  
    private String Classification;

    @Column(name = "GPA")
    private double GPA;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="Student")
    @JoinColumn(name = "FacultyID")
    private Faculty Mentor;

    @Column(name = "CreditHours")
    private int CreditHours;

    public Student()
    {

    }
    public Student(String studentID, String classification, double gpa, String mentorID, int creditHours)
    {
        //this.StudentID = studentID;
        this.Classification = classification;
        this.GPA = gpa;
        //this.MentorID = mentorID;
        this.CreditHours = creditHours;
    }
    public String getClassification()
    {
        return Classification;
    }
    public void setClassification(String classification)
    {
        this.Classification = classification;
    }
    public double getGPA()
    {
        return GPA;
    }
    public void setGPA(int gpa)
    {
        this.GPA = gpa;
    }
    public Faculty getMentor()
    {
        return Mentor;
    }
    public void setMentor(Faculty mentor)
    {
        this.Mentor = mentor;
    }
    public int getCreditHours()
    {
        return CreditHours;
    }
    public void setCreditHours(int creditHours)
    {
        this.CreditHours = creditHours;
    }
}
```

Faculty.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity  
@Table(name = "Faculty")  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="FacultyID")
public class Faculty extends Person
{
    @Column(name = "Rank")  
    private String Rank;
    @Column(name = "Salary")
    private int Salary;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Faculty")
    private Set<Student> allStudents;

    public Faculty()
    {

    }
    public Faculty(String facultyID, String rank, int salary)
    {
        //this.FacultyID = facultyID;
        this.Rank = rank;
        this.Salary = salary;
    }
    public String getRank()
    {
        return Rank;
    }
    public void setName(String rank)
    {
        this.Rank = rank;
    }
    public int getSalary()
    {
        return Salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary)
    {
        this.Salary = salary;
    }

    public Set<Student> getAllStudents()
    {
        return allStudents;
    }
    public void setAllStudents(Set<Student> allStuds)
    {
        this.allStudents = allStuds;
    }
}
```

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
Name    char (20),
ID      char (9) NOT NULL,
Address char (30),
DOB     date,
PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacultyID       char (9) NOT NULL,
Rank            char (12),
Salary          int,
PRIMARY KEY (FacultyID),
FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID) REFERENCES Person(ID));

CREATE TABLE Student (
StudentID       char (9) NOT NULL,
Classification  char (10),
GPA             double,
MentorID        char (9),
CreditHours     int,
PRIMARY KEY (StudentID),
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Person(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (MentorID) REFERENCES Faculty(FacultyID));
```

I have tried several different annotations after looking at documentation but I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Faculty` entity you should point the right property, not the type:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="Mentor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Student> allStudents;
```

plus, in your `Student` entity, the relationship with `Faculty` is `ManyToOne`, not `OneToOne`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MentorID")
private Faculty Mentor;
```

Comment: I changed it but it now says "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Student.Mentor in Faculty.allStudents".

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define student and faculty relation.

1. **Many To Many:** A student can have more than one faculty and a faculty can have more than one student.

That means you need to ManyToMany relation.

**Student Table**

```
id
name
bla
bla
```

**Faculty Table**

```
id
name
bla
bla
```

**Faculty Stundent Relation Table**

```
id
student_id
faculty_id
```

And here is your hibernate mapping:

**Stundent.class**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "faculty_student_rel", catalog = "yourDb", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FACULTY_ID",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Faculty> getFaculties() {
        return this.faculties;
    }
```

**Faculty.class**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "faculties")
    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return this.students;
    }
```

2. **Many to One:** A student can have only one faculty and a faculty can have more than one student.

For this situation you can use @Matteo Baldi's solution.